# Error: ',' expected in ckEditor node module files

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-plugin

I am trying to do a POC of ckEditor in my project and following the [official doc](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/angular.html)

After installing the dependencies I am getting error while running using `ng serve` the project.

[image: Error]

I am using Ionic With Angular 12 and below are the details

[image]

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

This is tsconfig file and I am using `"typescript": "~4.2.4"`

it seems like TypeScript is having trouble with the type keyword.
but from TypeScript version 3.8 or later, the type keyword is not required when importing types.

If it is the case so can someone please tell what I am missing or Do I need to update my Angular version?

Comment: which version are using of ckEditor

Comment: @DEV I am using ckEditor5

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not related to tsconfig but to dependencies.
Check compability between your version of ckeditor and angular/cli.